# Accessing a method within a class within a class in the NativeWifi library

Tags: c#

This is a question on the basic use of C# and classes. I'm trying to make windows refresh its list of detected access points. So I'm trying to call method `scan()` (see code at bottom). It is a method within a class within a class, so I tried to call it like this...

```
var v1 = new WlanClient.WlanInterface(); //Error 'NativeWifi.WlanClient.WlanInterface' has no constructors defined
v1.Scan();
```

And like this...

```
WlanClient.WlanInterface.Scan();  //Error An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property
```

Similar answers on this kind of thing suggest it is to do with internal properties but i dont understand if this is relevant to me or not.

```
namespace NativeWifi
{
    public class WlanClient
    {
        public WlanClient();

        public WlanClient.WlanInterface[] Interfaces { get; }

        public string GetStringForReasonCode(Wlan.WlanReasonCode reasonCode);

        public class WlanInterface
        {
            public bool Autoconf { get; set; }
            public Wlan.Dot11BssType BssType { get; set; }
            public int Channel { get; }
            public Wlan.WlanConnectionAttributes CurrentConnection { get; }
            public Wlan.Dot11OperationMode CurrentOperationMode { get; }
            public string InterfaceDescription { get; }
            public Guid InterfaceGuid { get; }
            public string InterfaceName { get; }
            public Wlan.WlanInterfaceState InterfaceState { get; }
            public NetworkInterface NetworkInterface { get; }
            public int RSSI { get; }

            public event WlanClient.WlanInterface.WlanConnectionNotificationEventHandler WlanConnectionNotification;
            public event WlanClient.WlanInterface.WlanNotificationEventHandler WlanNotification;
            public event WlanClient.WlanInterface.WlanReasonNotificationEventHandler WlanReasonNotification;

            protected void Connect(Wlan.WlanConnectionParameters connectionParams);
            public void Connect(Wlan.WlanConnectionMode connectionMode, Wlan.Dot11BssType bssType, string profile);
            public void Connect(Wlan.WlanConnectionMode connectionMode, Wlan.Dot11BssType bssType, Wlan.Dot11Ssid ssid, Wlan.WlanConnectionFlags flags);
            public bool ConnectSynchronously(Wlan.WlanConnectionMode connectionMode, Wlan.Dot11BssType bssType, string profile, int connectTimeout);
            public void DeleteProfile(string profileName);
            public Wlan.WlanAvailableNetwork[] GetAvailableNetworkList(Wlan.WlanGetAvailableNetworkFlags flags);
            public Wlan.WlanBssEntry[] GetNetworkBssList();
            public Wlan.WlanBssEntry[] GetNetworkBssList(Wlan.Dot11Ssid ssid, Wlan.Dot11BssType bssType, bool securityEnabled);
            public Wlan.WlanProfileInfo[] GetProfiles();
            public string GetProfileXml(string profileName);
            public void Scan();
            public Wlan.WlanReasonCode SetProfile(Wlan.WlanProfileFlags flags, string profileXml, bool overwrite);

            public delegate void WlanConnectionNotificationEventHandler(Wlan.WlanNotificationData notifyData, Wlan.WlanConnectionNotificationData connNotifyData);

            public delegate void WlanNotificationEventHandler(Wlan.WlanNotificationData notifyData);

            public delegate void WlanReasonNotificationEventHandler(Wlan.WlanNotificationData notifyData, Wlan.WlanReasonCode reasonCode);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This wouldn't even compile to begin with - the constructor in WlanClient lacks a body for instance - is this code from Visual Studio's "decompiled" metadata of a third party library?

Comment: the first way you are calling it is correct, the second way is incorrect as the class is not static and requires an instance however I am not sure why this class does not contain a default constructor

Comment: But, basically, if you read the documentation you should be able to do `var client = new WlanClient();` and then `var interfaces = client.Interfaces;`. It's even right there in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see the state of available Wifi interfaces, use:

```
var client = new WlanClient();
foreach(var wifiInterface in  wifi.Interfaces)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", wifiInterface.InterfaceName, 
                                 wifiInterface.InterfaceState);
}
```

To scan the first interface, use:

```
var client = new WlanClient();
var wifiInterface = client.Interfaces.First();
wifiInterface.Scan()
```

Comment: Thanks, Can I ask, how did you figured this out? I hovered over the WlanClient and clicked on 'show definition' and tried to figure it out from this code (as pasted in my question). Is this what you normally do to figure out how to use libraries?

Comment: Your issue was trying `var v1 = new WlanClient.WlanInterface();` rather than `var v1 = new WlanClient();`, it is not possible to create a `new` interface, only classes that implement interfaces. Once the line was corrected, it was simple enough to check out the intellisense and make some sensible deductions.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. Appreciated.